# Unable to start activity through fcm notification when the app is terminated or in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, ring

I need to start a device ring activity one i recived an fcm notification.Its working fine when the app is in forground.if the app is in background or in terminated state i am reciving the notification but the activity is not getting started

```
operation.setStatus(resources.getString(R.string.operation_value_completed));
        resultBuilder.build(operation);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(resources.getString(R.string.intent_extra_type), resources.getString(R.string.intent_extra_ring));
        intent.putExtra(resources.getString(R.string.intent_extra_message_text), resources.getString(R.string.intent_extra_stop_ringing));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    
        if (Constants.DEBUG_MODE_ENABLED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ringing is activated on the device");
        }
```

Comment: You need handle this on first activity of your app.

Comment: this might help: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages